# Wordpress pre-build slider

Tags: plugin-development, slideshow

Does wordpress 3+ brings a default images slider feature? Or is it just the template I downloaded?

If it brings a pre-build slider, how should I customize, add more features to it? I want to modify it to allow some content sliding features (like on: http://www.iwebix.de/front-slider-wordpress-plugin/) and not only images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WordPress does not have a slider feature built in. It will be either a plugin or your theme that has added the slider.

For modifying or adjusting your slider, please go to the support area for the plugin/theme you used.

If you wish to develop your own, there are many, many tutorials out there you can use, ( I personally recommend NivoSlider ), but how to add a slider to a WordPress site is beyond the scope of this question.